# How to change the OG url in a Twitter card with metadata?

Tags: twitter, metadata, reflect-metadata

[Example card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkMcs.png)

I would like to change the bbc.com URL to another URL. I have changed the metadata within my HTML, but it seems to keep showcasing 'bbc.com'. There is other people who are able to succesfully change it to display another URL.

I have tried everything, from adding a manifest.json with my own website's URL and card data but it was still showing 'bcc.com'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following line:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://myurl.com/my-page" />
```

All in all you should have:

```
<meta name="og:description" content="This is where the description of my webpage goes." />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Description of My Image">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://myurl.com/my-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://myurl.com/my-page" />
```

Comment: I have all of this. It still does not show. It shows the original web URL which I am trying to change.

Comment: Try adding a # to the end of the URL in your web browser.